# Python checking and creating multiple csv file paths efficiently

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm able to do this inefficiently, but would like some help around efficiency.

I have multiple queries and would like to create sample CSV files to load for analysis within my Jupyter notebook (rather than query each time).

```
# csv path
csv_path = os.environ.get('home')+'/csv/'
sample = csv_path + 'df1.csv'

# check if path exists and load
if os.path.exists(sample):
      print("loading")
      df_1 = pd.read_csv(sample)
# if path doesn't exist then query the table from a query dictionary
else:
      print("fetching")
      df_1 = table_query(cursor,list(query_dict.values())[0],sample)

print("complete")
```

There are about 10 queries in the query dictionary, so rather than do each individually and create a dataframe, I'd like to do this more efficiently by using the query dictionary, but I'm stuck.

So rather than doing this, doing something more efficient -

```
# csv path
csv_path = os.environ.get('home')+'/csv/'
sample = csv_path + 'df1.csv'
sample2 = csv_path + 'df2.csv'

# check if path exists and load
if os.path.exists(sample):
      print("loading")
      df_1 = pd.read_csv(sample)
# if path doesn't exist then query the table from a query dictionary
else:
      print("fetching")
      df_1 = table_query(cursor,list(query_dict.values())[0],sample)

print("complete")

if os.path.exists(sample2):
      print("loading")
      df_2 = pd.read_csv(sample2)
# if path doesn't exist then query the table from a query dictionary
else:
      print("fetching")
      df_2 = table_query(cursor,list(query_dict.values())[1],sample2)

print("complete")
```

Comment: To me, your question looks more like a SQL question that python question. Is it possible to join your 10 queries in single query and fetch all data in a single query? If you can share the SQL, we can probably give it a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately for this use case it can't be combined into a single query, I need them to be separate subqueries. The SQL is just ```query_dict.values())[0]``` through [10]. I was thinking it was more about efficiency of structure within python